# Override Angular Material Typography Margins

Tags: angular, themes, angular-material2, typography

It seems that applying a display class such as `mat-display-1` also adds `margin-bottom` css to an element. When creating a custom theme I know how to override the size, line-height and weight but is there any way to control how much margin gets added?

Comment: Just had a look at [the source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/8050f633b56b6c048fc72dad2ab79304afdfad19/src/lib/core/typography/_typography.scss) and it doesn't seem possible. Made an issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14240).

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar problem.

So as a workaround you can do `style="margin: 0"`

OR

Use this [css utility thing](https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/30da4bf9a6c9b9b5cc0aebac512ca7c9#gistcomment-2592042) so you can just go like `class="mat-headline m0"`

This way you just overriding the margin, should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about for all the other mat typography levels? It seems like Material has added a bottom margin to all levels.

I ended up adding this to my styles.scss file

```
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Update]
Angular-12 syntax to above solution,
class="mat-display-1 mb-4"
[h2 html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/162Qn.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).